# Laravel 5.6 search wherebetween

Tags: laravel

This is working as well. But problem is when i didnt search anything there is no results are in there. i mean `projects?startdate=&enddate=&search=` there is no results are in there. I just dont get it. why

```
$search = $request->get('search');
$startdate = $request->input('startdate');
$enddate = $request->input('enddate');
        $projects = $projects
            ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhereRaw("(firstname) LIKE '%$search%'")
                    ->orWhereRaw("(register) LIKE '%$search%'");
            })
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startdate, $enddate])
            ->orderBy("created_at", 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);
        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
```

Comment: What do you expect it to return? Seems like it's working as intended to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't search anything, `$search`, `$startdate` and  `$enddate` are `null`.
`whereBetween()` doesn't work with `null` values.

Only add constraints to the query when the variables have values:

```php
$query = $projects->query();

if(!is_null($search)) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('firstname', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('register', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
    })
}

if(!is_null($startdate) && !is_null($enddate)) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$startdate, $enddate])
}

$projects = $query->orderBy("created_at", 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

**Don't use something like `->orWhereRaw("(firstname) LIKE '%$search%'")`.

It's a huge security risk:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I added an important security warning to my answer, please take a look.

Comment: oh i heard SQL Injection before. Omg sir thank you so much indeed.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possible ways:

1. Either check for both date variables against null value and then
   append it to query filter

   ```
   $startdate = $request->input('startdate');
   $enddate = $request->input('enddate');

   if(!is_null($startdate) && !is_null($enddate)) {
       $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$startdate, $enddate]
   }
   ```
2. Or default values can be set to date range if not supplied in
   request.

   ```
   /* if startdate value is null, it will set default date, as 1 year back from current date */
   $startdate = $request->input('startdate', Carbon::now()->subYears(1)); 

   /* if enddate value is null, it will set default date, as current date */
   $enddate = $request->input('enddate', Carbon\Carbon::now());
   ```